# CSS not imported in Grapesjs Components

Tags: javascript, grapesjs

> working in grapesjs adding templates as components with add CSS but CSS not import. Also tried the public/index.html file but not working. Help!

```
          canvas: {
                   styles:[
         '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/assets/css/headers/style.css" type="style.css" />',
         '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/assets/css/headers/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />',
                      ],
                },
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with GrapesJS, but as far as I could understand from their website, the style property is used for specifying CSS Rulesets, and not <link> tags. They also have a section on how to [load external CSS](https://grapesjs.com/docs/modules/Components.html#external-css).

Answer (score 1):

You only need to specify the URL of the stylesheet, not the entire link tag.

```
canvas: {
    styles:[
        'http://localhost:3000/assets/css/headers/style.css',       
        'http://localhost:3000/assets/css/headers/bootstrap.css'
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's Working on removing link tags and only defining with localhost link.

```
 canvas: {
    styles:[
            'http://localhost:3000/assets/css/headers/style.css',       
            'http://localhost:3000/assets/css/headers/bootstrap.css'
           ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call from local driectory like : `C:/documents/[your project source]/`
Not go with localhost